# SQLite cast AS: syntax error with SQLite v2.8.17

Tags: sqlite, casting

I get:

```
$ echo "SELECT cast((strftime('%s','2017-11-01 22:25:28')-strftime('%s','2017-10-15 12:40:28')) AS real)/60/60 AS elapsed_hours;" | sqlite
SELECT cast((strftime('%s','2017-11-01 22:25:28')-strftime('%s','2017-10-15 12:40:28')) AS real)/60/60 AS elapsed_hours;
SQL error: near "AS": syntax error

$ sqlite
SQLite version 2.8.17
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> SELECT cast((strftime('%s','2017-11-01 22:25:28')-strftime('%s','2017-10-15 12:40:28')) AS real)/60/60 AS elapsed_hours;
SQL error: near "AS": syntax error
```

However, that exact same SQL

```
SELECT cast((strftime('%s','2017-11-01 22:25:28')-strftime('%s','2017-10-15 12:40:28')) AS real)/60/60 AS elapsed_hours;
```

works fine on http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/tryit/query/sqlite-date/

what's wrong? My SQLite is:

```
$ apt-cache policy sqlite
sqlite:
  Installed: 2.8.17-14fakesync1
  Candidate: 2.8.17-14fakesync1
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.17-14fakesync1 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

thx

Comment: SQLite 2.8 is pretty old, are you sure it supports CAST?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, thanks @muistooshort, I thought my latest ubuntu has the latest SQLite,

but after investigation, I found that I should install/use `sqlite3` instead of `sqlite`.

```
$ apt-get install sqlite3 sqlite-
```